# \left\left is an error?

Tags: delimiters, missing

I am new to LaTex. I am trying to copy some equations from Mathematica as LaTex and for certain equations, the string contains "\left\left". An example:

```
\begin{equation}
\omega _3-\omega _2\gg \left\left| \omega _1-\omega _2\right\right|
\end{equation}\newline
```

This gives an error: ! Missing delimiter (. inserted)

Am I correct that \left\left is meaningless? That \left should always be accompanied by something e.g. `\left\{` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct: `\left` *must* be followed by a delimiter or by `.` If you want a double bar for the norm, use `\left\|...\right\|`, but in the given case you just need `\|...\|` or (better) `\lVert...\rVert`. `\newline` after `\end{equation}` is wrong.

Comment: also do not over use `\left` there should be no `\left` or `\right` in your example.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's not really accurate to say that `\left\left` (or `\right\right`) is "meaningless".  It's absolutely an error, and if Mathematica is producing it, they should be informed and scolded.

Answer (score 1):

The software producing that code is flawed: `\left\left` and `\right\right` is nonsense.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is what perhaps the software wanted to produce
\begin{equation}
\omega _3-\omega _2\gg \left|\left| \omega _1-\omega _2\right|\right|
\end{equation}
but this is wrong anyway and should possibly be
\begin{equation}
\omega _3-\omega _2\gg \left\| \omega _1-\omega _2\right\|
\end{equation}
but neither is actually the right one: there is no need for growing
delimiters in this case
\begin{equation}
\omega _3-\omega _2\gg \lVert \omega _1-\omega _2 \rVert
\end{equation}
Finally, if the software produces \verb|\newline| after
\verb|\end{equation}|, it's another error.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The space between the double bars in (1) is definitely wrong. If you look closely, (2) is not really centered, because `\right\|` adds a small space after it.

Only (3) is fully right.

Never add `\newline` after `\end{equation}` (if the software adds it, remove).

Comment: Thanks everyone.